# Android notifications play sound from assets folder

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-resources, android-assets

I'm trying to play notifications sound from the assets folder, but when notification triggers the notification is shown but no sound is played and there is no error or warning in the logCat. I'm using this code for creating notifications:

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    // Set Icon
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    // Set Ticker Message
                    .setTicker(message)
                    // Set Title
                    .setContentTitle(message)
                    // Set Text
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    // Add an Action Button below Notification
                    .addAction(R.drawable.share,
                            context.getString(R.string.share), pendingShare)
                    // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    // Dismiss Notification
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(
                            Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/"
                                    + prefs.getString(Constants.NOTIF_SOUND,
                                            "mp3/al_affassi_full.mp3")));
```

can someone help me solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your mp3 file under `raw` folder. If you put it under `asset/` it's going to be compressed twice and you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named `raw` under `res`, and copy your mp3 file into that folder.

Then you can set,

```
setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"your package name"/"
                    + R.raw.your_map3_name);
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Android notifications play sound from raw folder   
 try
    {

        int res_sound_id = MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier("sound name", "raw", MainActivity.this.getPackageName());
        Uri u= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "/" +res_sound_id );

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };
        Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setContentTitle("Its time to Pray")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(u)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```